# GAE - Different Project for different clients or Different version of the same application for different clients?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on a system on GAE that includes app server, Datastore, a mobile app and a web client.
My each customer will need to have a customized (separate) app server, datastore, mobile app and a web client. I am not able to find any information on how I should design my system:

[Option A]:-Separate project for each customer, hence app server and datastore will be available exclusively for that customer. In the sense, do I need to clone my base project for each of my customers and then customize to have separate datastore and appservers ?

OR

[Option B]:-Same project with different versions of application for each customer. In this case, can I have individual (exclusive) data store and app server for each customer? In the sense, I want a separate datastore and app server for each customers. I am not sure if I can take advantage of using different datastore buckets for different customers for my requirement.

[image: Option A]
[image: Option B]
I could not find any reference link addressing my problem.
Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider App Engine's native [support of multitenancy](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy). If this is not good enough for your requirements, then you will have to create a separate project for each customer. The Datastore for a single project is shared across all versions, so you will not be able to segment it (unless you are ok using namespaces as described in the linked doc).

I would also recommend making sure that you actually need to have separate applications running for each customer. Unless you sign up for a [premier account](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/premier/), you have a limited number of projects that you can create. Besides that, it will most likely make management of those apps much more difficult for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer.I went through Multitenancy docs and found that using namespace api i can separate data from multiple clients without polluting a central datastore. So is it means that using name space api i am creating partition of same datastore?and thats the case how to share data between multiple client? one more question say i have two different projects so i would be having two different datastore ,than using name space api can i access a projects datastore from another app(project)?

Comment: Namespaces are simply a prefix on your Datastore entity keys. So any sharing and access control will actually have to be handled by your application. You cannot use namespaces to go across projects as namespaces are restricted to a single project. The only current way to access the datastore from a different project is using Cloud Datastore or Remote API, however these are not recommend for use from inside App Engine.

Comment: You have mention in  above comment that "The only current way to access the datastore from a different project is using Cloud Datastore or Remote API".so, here term cloud datastore means app engines datastore?or is it different ?and can you please provide me some link or tutorial on how access datastore(of other project) using cloud datastore.